# How to convert stringified data to an object?

Tags: php, ajax, json

My php has `header('Content-type: application/json')` and a `json_encode`.
The ajax code I use to send the data to the php file has `dataType: 'json'` and I am sending the data as a string (`json.stringify`).
The problem is, I can't make `$_POST['data']` work on a string.
Any way to convert it to an object?
edit: What I am trying to achieve is, sending data from ajax to php where a query looks up the information from the database and the php file sends an array using JSON to the ajax and the ajax displays it.
Ajax:

```
function op_prof(obj) {
    var xval = obj.id;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../script/profile.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'u_search':'xval'}),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        alert({u_search:xval}['u_search']);
        $("#co_profile").html(data).show();
    }
  });
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__). '/../script/config.php');
session_start();
$id = $_POST['u_search'];
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='$id'") as $row) {
    $fullname = $row['FullName'];
    $data = array("u_data"=> true,"inpt"=>"<p>My name is " . $fullname . "</p>");
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>

<?php $pdo = null; ?>
```

I'd also like to know any other way of achieving this (even without using JSON)

Comment: show some relevant code pls..

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json-decode), no?

Comment: Can you `print_r($data);` and show in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_decode("php://input");`